# How to add additional space in primary partition without deleting secondary partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I two partitions on my harddisk
1)  C:
2   D:

C drive is full now and D drive also contain data, what i want to do is to add some additional space to C by getting space from D drive. 
Is it possible to get additional space from D without getting data lost or deleting the partition d

Answer (score 0):

There are many partition managers that will do this for you. I have mostly used the `gparted` partition editor from an Ubuntu Live CD to shrink/expand/move partitions and found it reliable for Windows partitions.

You must of course back up first. If your data are important you will have a running back-up, and if unimportant then you may as well delete D:, which will simplify the job.

If you want to stay with Windows tools there is Partition Wizard on [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), which also has `gparted`.

Comment: I don't want to delete the d: drive and backing up the whole data in d: isn't a possibility either. That why i prefer a tool that can do this with either deleting any drive

Comment: gparted can `resize` partitions.

Comment: I cannot believe that you have valuable data that you haven't backed up. Sooner or later your disc will fail and you must anticipate that. To me the equation is simple: if it's valuable, it's backed up; if it's not backed up, it isn't valuable. Now might be the time to buy that external drive, before you start moving and resizing partitions. At ~£50 for 2TB in UK, it's a small price to pay for data security. Then you can start shuffling you partitions with an easy mind.